# Rename image during upload

Tags: php

I'm currently wanting to use the w3schools image uploading code until I can find the one I coded a while back. Anyway:

```
<?php
 $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
 $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
 if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
 && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
 && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
 {
 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
 echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
}
 }
else
{
 echo "Invalid file";
 }
?>
```

Basically what I want to happen is when the user uploads the file it renames the file name to $username and not the original name so all it would be is username.png instead of what I currently have username-38474.png

Any help?

Comment: Ever heard of W3Fools? Your (their) code can be easily hacked by sending fake `mime-type`. Be aware of that.

Comment: @Tomáš Zato that's why I'm only using it until I can find my code again, couldn't be bothered recoding :P

Comment: @TomášZato Yes, it can be faked, but it isn't a danger: the file extension is checked and the apache registers its handlers by extension.

Comment: This is good against actual hacking, but its still nice to prevent people from turning the image upload to "anything upload".

Comment: @TomášZato Fake mime, let end it with .gif... This program doesn't check if it's a valid image. This is what you really need.

Comment: I hoped my last comment was enough of acknowledgement to that fact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

This line of code basically renames the image to a new location: to `"upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]`, so replace this line by:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/".$username.".".$extension);
```

Answer (score 0):

So just pass different parameter to `move_uploaded_file`:

```
$extension = explode("/", $_FILES["file"]["type"]);  //Use proper mime type here, $_FILES contents can be faked by remote user
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $username.".".$extension[1]);
```

Comment: I don't think that you can fake the extension here as it is already checked against an array.

Comment: My warning was more about the actual checking. If put simply, I'd say that he must first know it **is** the right mime type.